Berkovitch completion, separable closure, and algebraic closure
I am wondering if it is always possible to take the Berkovich completion after the algebraic closure of a field, to the effect that one does not need to take the algebraic closure afterwards or the Berkovich completion before. Let $C$ be the Berkovich completion functor and $A$ is the algebraic closure functor, defined on fields. My question has two parts:
$$ C \circ A \circ C \cong C \circ A \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (a)$$
(I can't show off of the top of my head that the Berkovich completion is a field).
The other part of the question asks whether
$$A \circ C \circ A \cong C \circ A \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (b)$$
If this is true, then one need not take the algebraic closure of the completion if the completion was of a field which was already algebraically closed.
If both (a) and (b) hold, then any composition of functors involving $C$ and $A$ in which both are applied at least once and in which $C$ comes after $A$ at least once is the same as $C \circ A$.
Example: For the case of the field of rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$,
The Adeles can be formed from the Berkovitch completion of the rational numbers

The algebraic closure of the Adeles is not complete. Its completion is $\mathbb{C}_1$
The completion of the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is defined as $\mathbb{C}_p$, and it is separably closed

In this case, my question asks whether the Berkovich completion of the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ is the same as the Berkovich completion of the separable closure of the Adeles $\mathbb{A}$.
Progress on (a) Here I might like to consider a universal property for Berkovich completion demonstrating that a ring homomorphism from a field K into a Berkovich complete field L extends uniquely along the canonical map $\eta_K : K \rightarrow C(K)$. This determines $C(K)$ up to isomorphism.
$C \circ A$ applied to the map $(\eta_K)$ gives a morphism one way, with the other more difficult.
For the other direction, we would like to construct a map from $A \circ C$ to $C \circ A$. To do this we can pass through $A \circ C \circ A$ using the injection $i_A : \text{Id} \rightarrow A$ and the availability of (b).
Progress on (b) For $a = (a_0,...,a_n) \in K^{n+1}$ a vector in an algebraically closed field $K$, we can expand $p = \Pi_i (z - a_i)$ to obtain $\Sigma_i z^i c^K_i(a)$ and consider the function $c^K : K^{n+1} \rightarrow K^{n+1}$.
This construction appears to produce a commutative diagram with respect to completion featuring $c^{C(K)}$, $c^K$, and the product of completions, which is isomorphic to the completion of the (finite) products. If this is true, then maybe one can use the dense image and a lemma about injective functions between Berkovich complete fields being isomorphisms to demonstrate that the Berkovich completion of an an algebraically closed field is algebraically closed.
